# flexbox css centering and layout not working horizontally

Tags: css, navigation, flexbox

I am trying to center the content of a navbar for mobile devices.

It should have 3 divs, the far left div should be the 3 bars for menu expansion (hamburger), the middle div should contain the logo, and the far right div should contain 3 inputs.

The problem is it is centering horizontally based on the left edge of the far right div. [=        LOGO         input input input] but it looks like this
[=   LOGO         input input input]  if I take out all but 2 inputs 
[=      LOGO     [input]  it works perfectly but with 3 inputs it does not.

I have tried everything can anyone give me a clue as to why this won't work?
thanks

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 300px) {
  #hidden-nav {
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 8vh;
    background-color: rgb(101, 0, 0);
    display: flex;
    padding: 8px;
    min-width: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10002;
  }
}
#hidden-nav input {
  max-width: 15vw;
}
body {
}
#hidden-nav:first-child {
  /* padding-left: 2em; 
  border: 20px solid blue;*/
}
.bar {
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 6px 0;
}
#container-for-right-hidden-nav {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="hidden-nav" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white; align-items:">
    <div class="" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div style=""> <img height="35" width="50" src="https://seohackercdn-seohacker.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Link-Searching.jpg?x68951" alt="logo" /> </div>
    <img height="35" width="50" src="https://seohackercdn-seohacker.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Link-Searching.jpg?x68951" alt="logo" /> 
</div>
<div id="container-for-right-hidden-nav"> 
 <a href="/">
     <input type="button" style="background-color: dodgerBlue;" value="floorplans">
    </a> 
    <a href="/">
     <input type="button" style="background-color: green;" value="apply">
    </a> 
    <a href="/">
     <input type="button" style="background-color: #003059;" value="contact">
    </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit that part where you want to present LOGO.

Comment: ? I'm confused what do you mean?

Comment: The part where you explain how it should look. It looks generic. This part:  [= LOGO input input input] but it looks like this [= LOGO input input input] if I take out all but 2 inputs [= LOGO [input] it works perfectly but with 3 inputs it does not. I guess you wanted to present images.

Comment: I was just showing what it should look like.  If you run the code  I put up it will show you how it looks.  Apples mobile nav at 320 is how mine should look but with more 3 elements in the far right div where as apple on has one element in their far right div.  If they had 3 like me they I suspect would have the same problems

Comment: Ok. Thought you had problem with uploading image.

Comment: There are a couple syntax issues you may want to address before moving on.  There is an extra closing div in the html and an extra closing bracket in the css.  Hint: You may want to align-self on the on the items you want centered.

Comment: Not even once you've accepted an answer given to your questions. Aren't you aware you are suppose to? ... By doing that you'll most likely will attract more users.

Comment: No answers are good. they are all 100% wrong. I'm confused though if I am supposed to do more than respond.  I thought I only rate correct answers?

Comment: Interesting, in a comment on the first question i checked you wrote _"Thank you very much for your help. This worked great."_ ... in another _"Hey thanks so to be clear it's impossible to do it the way I am trying to do it because the router doesn't know about the view. Thank you."_ ... and for me, both were 100% correct. Btw, there are more than those 2 that is good enough.

Comment: You should rate answers that are helpful, and additionally, an answer that lead to a solution is also good enough to be accepted, even if it doesn't cover all parts.

Answer (score 1):

Try justify Content center and align-items center.
Hope it Helps.

```
#hidden-nav {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items:center;
height: 8vh;
background-color: rgb(101, 0, 0);

padding: 8px;
min-width: 80px;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10002; }
}
```

Comment: that was the first thing I tried it didn't. That's what's wierd.  It only centers based on the left corner of the far right div.  It's wierd.  If I take every element out but the logo it centers perfectly.  I put other elements in and it won't anymore.

Comment: Actually as I look at apples I don't think it's possible to center the items the way I want to .  That is why no one tries to have a mobile nav with more than 3 items I suspect.  You can't center anymore perfectly

Comment: maybe place all items in a wrapper div then center it?

Comment: It centers all elements perfectly if they are together.  But if you put 3 divs in the mobile nav it won't center all 3.  It centers them based on the size of the divs.  If you have 3 divs 1 200 px  and 1 300 px and 1 50 pixels. Centering should still be in the center. It shouldn't matter how big the divs are but it does and I don't know why.